# Pyspark code with Spigot function not working in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am new to AWS Glue.  As per AWS Glue documentation, Spigot function will help you to write sample records from a dynamicFrame to an S3 Directory.  But when I run this, it is not creating any file under that S3 directory.  Any inputs on where I am doing wrong.  Below is the test code.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "amssurveydb", table_name = "amssurvey", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

split1 = SplitRows.apply(datasource0, {"count": {">": 50}}, "split11", "split12", transformation_ctx ="split1")## @type: SplitRows

selFromCol1 = SelectFromCollection.apply(dfc = split1, key = "split11", transformation_ctx = "selFromCol1")

selFromCol2 = SelectFromCollection.apply(dfc = split1, key = "split12", transformation_ctx = "selFromCol2")

spigot1 = Spigot.apply(frame = selFromCol1, path = "s3://asgqatestautomation3/SourceFiles/spigot1Op", options = {"topk":5},transformation_ctx ="spigot1")



job.commit()
```